# How to convert array to Gray Scale Image output?

Tags: python, image, grayscale

I have the data in a txt.How should i do to convert the data to Gray Scale Image output?Thx!
The number of rows is 2378 and the number of columns is 5362.
[image]

I'm a noob in python.I have tried this,but it did not work.

```py
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image


def rdnumpy(txtname):
    f = open(txtname)
    line = f.readlines()
    lines = len(line)
    for l in line:
        le = l.strip('\n').split(' ')
        columns = len(le)
    A = zeros((lines, columns), dtype=int)
    A_row = 0
    for lin in line:
        list = lin.strip('\n').split(' ')
        A[A_row:] = list[0:columns]
        A_row += 1
    return A


A = rdnumpy('oop.txt')
im = Image.fromarray(array)
im = im.convert('L')
im.save('T7.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code with small changes (see `# <<<` in code):

```
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image


def rdnumpy(txtname):
    f = open(txtname)
    line = f.readlines()
    lines = len(line)
    for l in line:
        le = l.strip('\n').split(' ')
        columns = len(le)
    A = zeros((lines, columns), dtype=uint8) # <<< uint8
    A_row = 0
    for lin in line:
        list = lin.strip('\n').split(' ')
        A[A_row:] = list[0:columns]
        A_row += 1
    return A


A = rdnumpy('PIL_imgFromText.txt')
im = Image.fromarray(A) # <<< A
im = im.convert('L')
im.save('PIL_imgFromText.png')
```

creates in case of 'PIL_imgFromText.txt'

```
100 128 156
200 225 255
```

following grayscale image (magnified):

[image]

P.S.
Below a suggestion how the code of the function can be further improved:

```
import numpy as np
def rdnumpy_improved(txtname):
    lst = []
    with open(txtname) as f: 
        lines = f.readlines()
        imgSizeY = len(lines)
        imgSizeX = len(lines[0].strip('\n').split(' '))
    for line in lines:
        lst_c = line.strip('\n').split(' ')
        assert imgSizeX == len(lst_c)
        lst += lst_c
    A = np.array(lst, dtype=uint8).reshape((imgSizeY, imgSizeX))
    return A
```

and finally how the entire code can be shorten to a one-liner using `numpy.loadtxt()` function (as suggested in another answer)

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(np.loadtxt('PIL_imgFromText.txt', dtype=np.uint8)).save('PIL_imgFromText.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cv2 !

The `cvtColor()` function can turn colorfull image to gray scale image.

The first step here is to convert your text file into an image file (try in *.jpg*). Try to display your image to see if it worked, which has to be a color picture.

Once it is done, use `cv2` to turn your color image in gray image, and display it again to see your results.

You can use `cv2.imshow('windows_name', image)` to display images.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(im)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Gray Scale Image', img)
```

Your image *img* is now in a scale of gray.
Tell me if you failed to convert your text file to an image.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thx.But,my problem is just the first step you said.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a sample text file since none was provided with the question.

```
import numpy as np

# Make a 10x8 pixel image of increasing numbers
im = np.arange(80).reshape((8,10))

# Save in same format as OP in file called "data.txt"
np.savetxt('data.txt', im, fmt="%d")
```

That looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
```

---

Now for answering the question. You can load the image very simply and efficiently with Numpy, then make into an image and save like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Load image from text file, make into "PIL Image", save
im = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=np.uint8)
pi = Image.fromarray(im)
pi.save('result.png')
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Or, if you like one-liners:

```
Image.fromarray(np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=np.uint8)).save('result.png')
```